# How to specifiy internal operations (do/entry/exit..) in a state machine

Tags: state-machine, enterprise-architect

I'm using Enterprise Architect version 9, and I'm trying to draw a state machine diagram, in this diagram I want to draw internal operation (do/entry/exit..) as following :

[image]

I looked about a solution and all I can find is to draw a self transition and then set the "kind" of the transition to "internal", but it doesn't make any change: transition is still drawn like an external transition and thus the diagram is still wrong/looks wrong :

[image]

As I can notice it is not practicable to handle internal triggers in the operations compartment, since the "Action" type for the operation must be `entry`, `exit`, or `do` ("event" is not an option), nor is there any meaningful way to specify the event, since a transition is not an operation.

I'd appreciate any help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The entry/exit/do are just stereotyped operations of the state. From the context of the state in the diagram choose Features/Operations. Here your see the Action with you desired entry/exit/do.